# Why is this jQuery ajax button click event firing multiple times in MVC4 C#.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a MVC4 C#.Net project and when I am trying to
click the button `('#btn_rightArw_Dwn')` then the ajax call fires multiple times in MVC4. Why this is happening? Please look up on below jQuery code.

[image]

Below I have added jQuery code.

```js
$("#btn_rightArw_Dwn").click(function() {
  $('.fade_bg').show();
  var Masterid = $('#MastersId').val();
  var pgm_id = $('#program1').val();
  if ($('#rdclick').val() == "0") {

    $.ajax({

      url: "/DataInput/Arrow_Load_Down?Id=" + Masterid + "&flag=" + "Right" + "&type=" + 0 + "&pgm_id=" + pgm_id,
      async: true,
      data: {},
      success: function(data) {
        $('#DVmaster').html(data);
        $('#btn_rightArw1').attr('hidden', false);
        $('#btn_LeftArw1').attr('hidden', false);
        var production_id = $('#program1').val();

        $.ajax({

          url: "/DataInput/Arrow_Load_Details_Down?Id=" + Masterid + "&flag=" + "Right" + "&ProductnSts_id=" + pgm_id + "&type=" + 0,

          async: false,
          data: {},
          success: function(data) {

            $('#DVDetails').html(data);
            $('#DVDetails').show();
            $('#btn_rightArw_Dwn').attr('hidden', false);
            $('#btn_LeftArw_dwn').attr('hidden', false);

          },
          error: function(html) {
            $('.fade_bg').hide();
          }
        });

        var channelid = $("#channel1").val();
        var starttime = $("#StartTime").val();
        var Endtime = $("#EndTime").val();
        var date = $("#Date").val();
        var Vimpact = $("#Viewers").val();
        var gradeid = $("#grade1").val();
        var seclength = $("#Seconds option:selected").text();
        var Daypartid = $('#daypartid').val();
        var itemid = $('#item1 option:selected').val();
        var brandid = $("#brand1 option:selected").val();




        $.ajax({
          url: "/DataInput/Print_Labels_in_Edit?starttime=" + starttime + "&finishtime=" + Endtime + "&date=" + date + "&channelid=" + channelid + "&impact1=" + Vimpact + "&Seclength=" + seclength + "&gradesid=" + gradeid + "&itemid=" + itemid + "&brandid=" + brandid,

          cache: false,
          success: function(html) {
            var labels = html.split(',');
            var daypartname = labels[0];
            var CPH = labels[1];
            var TVR = labels[2];
            var Mediavalue = labels[3];
            var daypartid = labels[4];
            $('.fade_bg').hide();
            $('#lblDaypart').text(" " + daypartname);
            $("#lblCPH").text('£' + " " + CPH);
            $('#lblTvr').text(" " + TVR);
            $('#lblMediaValue').text(" " + "£ " + Mediavalue);
            $('#daypartid').val(daypartid);



          },
          error: function(html) {
            $('.fade_bg').hide();
          }
        });

      }

    });
  }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you programatically triggering your click events for this button? You currently have a single AJAX request that is being made and trigger two more within the success function of the current request. I don't see where you are incrementing your `MasterId` value however, which appears to be different in each of your requests in your console output.

Comment: What does your markup look like? Without knowing a bit more about how your page is organized, it's tough to determine exactly what might be going wrong.

Comment: No, Rion Williams. I am clicking the button on manually. And I am setting MasterId in Hidden Field. Like this  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MastersId)

Comment: I believe the button is not triggering multiple times whereas the failing request is being continuously re-tried. The requests are posted to a URL re-written page. Please verify the URL to which the request are being posted.

Comment: Not sure but what I see is that the request doesn't have `?Id=`.

Comment: This is likely the result of some custom routing that you have defined that uses the `Action/{id}` as the route definition, so it's mapping your `Id` query string to the appropriate route. I don't see anything that would cause the button to be triggered multiple times however.

Comment: Is the page being loaded in a standard way?  Or are you using some JavaScript framework to navigate around like jQuery Mobile or AngularJS?

Comment: Also that code snipped is not the full implementation.  How is that called on the page? Generally you can register events multiple times and they will all fire when you trigger that event type

Comment: I think @RionWilliams is on the right track. Doesn't appear to be anything related with the code posted.  It looks to be returning a 302 redirect so take a look at your routing and logs from the web server to see why it's redirecting.

Comment: Thank everyone who replayed me. MasterId is keeping 20 values (ie; " ",-1,-2,-3,-20) happened through each automatic repeat call when I did break point on controller then I can see that MasterId values. How it is happening that is MasterId is automatic carrying like this values?